# Is this a valid solution to the palindrome problem?

Tags: java, palindrome

Is my solution down below valid or am I relying too much on built in functions?
Just to give some context, suppose this was an interview question or something of similar magnitude.

```
    public static boolean palindrome(String s){
    char[] arr = new char[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        arr[i] = s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - i);
    }

    return s.compareTo(String.valueOf(arr)) == 0;
}
```

Comment: You could skip building the array and instead just check if character at index `i` is the same as character at index `s.length() - 1 - i`. As soon as that's false you return false.

Comment: Well, does it produce correct answers to all inputs? If it does then it is perfectly valid solution. If it is optimal is another question... Reminds me of some interview story, when someone was asked to sort an array, however he likes. Interviewee implemented bubble sort and said he's done. Is it valid solution? Of course, could merge sort be "better"? Maybe, but nobody asked him for fast sort function.

Comment: I agree 100% with zubergu. There is a difference between a working solution and an optimal solution. If your goal is to prepare for interviews, you should be able to answer both. IN FACT, a lot of interviewers will ask you to come up with a WORKING solution first, and then to optimize it.  That said, if you provide the optimal from the get go, you don't really have to worry about that. My suggestion, look up the optimal way and learn that.

Comment: If the solution gives you the correct answer, then it is a valid answer.  If you want an elegant answer?  Maybe.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies!
Using the tip I got from @FedericoklezCulloca I removed the array and instead of setting the array, i check: `if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - i))` and return false if the if-statement is true.

Regarding if my original solution gave the correct results - Yes it did but it felt like a really awful solution for such an easy problem!

Answer (score -1):

I don't claim this to be most optimal, but I will share it with you as I think it might be better than your answer.

If you think of a `String` as an array of characters, what if you create two pointers, one that points to the head and one that points to the tail and do a character-by-character comparison until the pointer indexes are the same or the tail pointer is lower than the head? This is how that looks in code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class PalindromeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> inputs = List.of("Otto", "Hello", "Delia saw I was ailed");

        for (String s : inputs) {
            System.out.println(s + " is palindrome? " + isPalindrome(s));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

        int headPtr = 0;
        int tailPtr = s.length() - 1;
        char[] chars = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        while (headPtr < tailPtr) {
            if (chars[headPtr] != chars[tailPtr]) {
                return false;
            }
            headPtr++;
            tailPtr--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You may have to ask if the solution need to be case-sensitive. My solution is not. Most times when I have seen this question, the person asking is interested in a case-insensitive solution. That's why I called `toLowerCase()`. Also (not that it matters that much), this solution doesn't reverse the string. It simply walks two pointers and compare the characters each one is pointing to. If a mismatch is encounter, I break immediately. That's why I think this solution is a bit more effective. I also don't need to use a comparator class.